# Database web application

Tags: php, database

How would i go about creating a php application for my web page that can extract data from my database (i currently get the data in a CSV file). id also like the user to be able to filter the data by certain parameters. can u help

Comment: Language? OS? Platform? DBMS?

Comment: can you expand a bit more on your needs, or even the platform that you're working with? PHP, MS Access, or Python? Are you needing a Content Management System on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any specific requirements, I would recommend looking for a web framework that features *scaffolding*. Scaffolding generally provides you with the ability to create, read, update, and destroy data in your database with zero effort spent coding. You may also be provided with features like sorting and pagination... all for free.

The following frameworks all provide scaffolding:

- [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) (Ruby)
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) (PHP)
- [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) (Java)
- [Seam](http://seamframework.org/) (Java)
- [Spring MVC](http://www.springsource.org/) (Java)

Since you mention PHP specifically, have a look at **CakePHP's official documentation on [scaffolding](http://book.cakephp.org/view/105/Scaffolding) and [bake](http://book.cakephp.org/view/113/Code-Generation-with-Bake)**, or [this tutorial](http://www.askaboutphp.com/33/cakephp-using-scaffolding.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to start with like

**A language**

```
1. Asp.net c#
2. PHP Mysql
3. JSP Oracle
```

**A server**

```
1. Apache
2. Windows
```

**A Framwework** (like explained in another answer by Dolph Mathews )

```
1. Ruby on Rails (Ruby)
2. CakePHP (PHP)
3. Grails (Java)
4. Seam (Java)
5. Spring MVC (Java)
6. Symphony (PHP)
7. Zend (PHP)
```

Since you want it in PHP, you have to use **php mysql** and **apache** server. You can use `WAMP` to install all three of this in one go.
http://www.wampserver.com/en/

With wamp, you will also get `phpMyAdmin`, through which you can manage your database, like create, delete, manipulate ...........

Coming to the coding part, that you are going to have to google

Here are some links of W3schools to get started with

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp

Comment: Seriously, you just copy and paste my answer?

Comment: @Mathews, I used you incomplete list and add few more, I didn't mentioned you, which I will correct. Thank You